# Error in your MySQL SQL syntax

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'am trying to insert a record in my MySQL database, the record should be inserted in table `medication_profile`,  but I get this error that says :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
>       You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
>       corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
>       ' medication_type, diabetic_id, times_a_day, dose) VALUES ('injections',2,1,'18')' 
>       at line 1

The code I'am using in java to insert this record is as follow:

```
PreparedStatement addMedicationStm = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO medication_profile"
            + ", medication_type, diabetic_id, times_a_day, dose) "
            + "VALUES (?,?,?,?))", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    addMedicationStm.setString(1, medication.getMedicationType());
    addMedicationStm.setInt(2, medication.getDiabeticID());
    addMedicationStm.setInt(3, medication.getTimesPerDay());
    addMedicationStm.setString(4, medication.getDose());
    addMedicationStm.executeUpdate();

    ResultSet rs = addMedicationStm.getGeneratedKeys();

    if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
        medication.setDiabeticID(rs.getInt(1));
        addMedicationStm.close();
        con.close();
    }
```

I can't find where the error is, as I see the insert syntax is correct

any suggestions?

thanks in advance

Comment: There's some typo in your MySQL query. There's no opening parenthesis. Please take a thoughtful look on your code before just copypasting it to StackOverflow.

Comment: You're missing an opening `(` after `medication_profile` I believe, and you have one `)` too much in the end of the SQL statement too.

Comment: Your prepared statement reads `INSERT INTO medication_profile, medication_type, diabetic_id, times_a_day, dose) VALUES (?,?,?,?))`. And you really don't see the error?

Comment: @TagirValeev in such cases please flag question as off-topic. Soon you will be able to vote for close.

Answer (score 4):

Your string query gets concatenated to:

```
INSERT INTO medication_profile, medication_type, diabetic_id, times_a_day, dose) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

which should be something like

```
INSERT INTO medication_profile (medication_type, diabetic_id, times_a_day, dose) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

Answer (score 3):

remove the comma after table name and add `(`

```
PreparedStatement addMedicationStm = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO medication_profile"
        + "(medication_type, diabetic_id, times_a_day, dose) "
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sql syntax is wrong here:

```
PreparedStatement addMedicationStm = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO medication_profile"
        + ", medication_type, diabetic_id, times_a_day, dose) "
        + "VALUES (?,?,?,?))", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

the syntax should be something like :

```
 PreparedStatement addMedicationStm = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO "
       + "yourtableName "
       + "(column1Name, column2Name,...) " 
       + "VALUES (?,?,...)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced your brackets and commas:

```
PreparedStatement addMedicationStm = 
    con.prepareStatement
        ("INSERT INTO medication_profile"
            + "(medication_type, diabetic_id, times_a_day, dose) "
            + "VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
```